# turn data gathered from api into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have scraped data from this [website](http://api.exchangeratesapi.io) and now I wanat to turn the data into a Pandas dataframe. The data looks like this:

```
'{"success":true,"timestamp":1625593144,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-07-06","rates":{"AED":4.341698,"AFN":93.972917,"ALL":122.468757,"AMD":585.816506,"ANG":2.121734,"AOA":761.303282,"ARS":113.370438,"AUD":1.578498,"AWG":2.127705,"AZN":2.009632,"BAM":1.952573,"BBD":2.386588,"BDT":100.252485,"BGN":1.955599,"BHD":0.445195,"BIF":2346.976313,"BMD":1.182058,"BND":1.589828,"BOB":8.161781,"BRL":6.127802,"BSD":1.182028,"BTC":3.4950642e-5,"BTN":87.924008,"BWP":12.897021,"BYN":3.002192,"BYR":23168.338316,"BZD":2.382625,"CAD":1.473897,"CDF":2367.662278,"CHF":1.09302,"CLF":0.031979,"CLP":882.394256,"CNY":7.658792,"COP":4489.988504,"CRC":732.757605,"CUC":1.182058,"CUP":31.324539,"CVE":110.676143,"CZK":25.649122,"DJF":210.075036,"DKK":7.437261,"DOP":67.518754,"DZD":158.993684,"EGP":18.544251,"ERN":17.733234,"ETB":52.335644,"EUR":1,"FJD":2.440927,"FKP":0.837894,"GBP":0.857223,"GEL":3.729425,"GGP":0.837894,"GHS":7.009351,"GIP":0.837894,"GMD":60.426644,"GNF":11637.361598,"GTQ":9.160718,"GYD":247.104642,"HKD":9.180933,"HNL":28.368955,"HRK":7.486799,"HTG":111.375788,"HUF":353.643356,"IDR":17154.67695,"ILS":3.871489,"IMP":0.837894,"INR":88.383014,"IQD":1726.395822,"IRR":49770.555467,"ISK":146.729013,"JEP":0.837894,"JMD":176.728936,"JOD":0.838143,"JPY":130.829938,"KES":127.602969,"KGS":100.225405,"KHR":4828.70738,"KMF":492.741079,"KPW":1063.852684,"KRW":1345.105273,"KWD":0.356032,"KYD":0.985044,"KZT":504.019189,"LAK":11227.187157,"LBP":1810.912689,"LKR":235.815617,"LRD":202.782408,"LSL":16.986265,"LTL":3.49031,"LVL":0.715015,"LYD":5.330971,"MAD":10.579128,"MDL":21.335608,"MGA":4556.833504,"MKD":61.566566,"MMK":1945.593749,"MNT":3364.135248,"MOP":9.455406,"MRO":421.99453,"MUR":50.597975,"MVR":18.200655,"MWK":945.64665,"MXN":23.647896,"MYR":4.912048,"MZN":75.09677,"NAD":16.986347,"NGN":486.419394,"NIO":41.578843,"NOK":10.281955,"NPR":140.678533,"NZD":1.686034,"OMR":0.455099,"PAB":1.182028,"PEN":4.613608,"PGK":4.143151,"PHP":58.847591,"PKR":187.179029,"PLN":4.511691,"PYG":8026.907563,"QAR":4.303918,"RON":4.927647,"RSD":117.38917,"RUB":87.864027,"RWF":1170.237497,"SAR":4.433619,"SBD":9.49454,"SCR":17.11642,"SDG":533.664832,"SEK":10.171125,"SGD":1.593295,"SHP":0.837894,"SLL":12149.192503,"SOS":691.503812,"SRD":24.918983,"STD":24124.027694,"SVC":10.342746,"SYP":1486.841937,"SZL":16.986436,"THB":38.157424,"TJS":13.481011,"TMT":4.137203,"TND":3.291439,"TOP":2.657207,"TRY":10.278705,"TTD":8.010435,"TWD":33.088998,"TZS":2741.192996,"UAH":32.237122,"UGX":4213.970207,"USD":1.182058,"UYU":51.636205,"UZS":12529.815471,"VEF":252759741497.0032,"VND":27198.565331,"VUV":128.183328,"WST":2.981119,"XAF":654.856251,"XAG":0.045298,"XAU":0.000659,"XCD":3.194571,"XDR":0.828707,"XOF":651.903598,"XPF":119.955315,"YER":295.810379,"ZAR":16.997052,"ZMK":10639.940699,"ZMW":26.781822,"ZWL":380.623092}}'
```

The dataframe should have the Currency as the index and only the Rate column
How can i fix please?

Comment: Are you looking for more than `df = pandas.DataFrame(data["rates"])`?

Comment: Actually yes, beacause when i use this i got `string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Json string, so parse it before creating a dataframe:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

s = '{"success":true,"timestamp":1625593144,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-07-06","rates":{"AED":4.341698,"AFN":93.972917,"ALL":122.468757,"AMD":585.816506,"ANG":2.121734,"AOA":761.303282,"ARS":113.370438,"AUD":1.578498,"AWG":2.127705,"AZN":2.009632,"BAM":1.952573,"BBD":2.386588,"BDT":100.252485,"BGN":1.955599,"BHD":0.445195,"BIF":2346.976313,"BMD":1.182058,"BND":1.589828,"BOB":8.161781,"BRL":6.127802,"BSD":1.182028,"BTC":3.4950642e-5,"BTN":87.924008,"BWP":12.897021,"BYN":3.002192,"BYR":23168.338316,"BZD":2.382625,"CAD":1.473897,"CDF":2367.662278,"CHF":1.09302,"CLF":0.031979,"CLP":882.394256,"CNY":7.658792,"COP":4489.988504,"CRC":732.757605,"CUC":1.182058,"CUP":31.324539,"CVE":110.676143,"CZK":25.649122,"DJF":210.075036,"DKK":7.437261,"DOP":67.518754,"DZD":158.993684,"EGP":18.544251,"ERN":17.733234,"ETB":52.335644,"EUR":1,"FJD":2.440927,"FKP":0.837894,"GBP":0.857223,"GEL":3.729425,"GGP":0.837894,"GHS":7.009351,"GIP":0.837894,"GMD":60.426644,"GNF":11637.361598,"GTQ":9.160718,"GYD":247.104642,"HKD":9.180933,"HNL":28.368955,"HRK":7.486799,"HTG":111.375788,"HUF":353.643356,"IDR":17154.67695,"ILS":3.871489,"IMP":0.837894,"INR":88.383014,"IQD":1726.395822,"IRR":49770.555467,"ISK":146.729013,"JEP":0.837894,"JMD":176.728936,"JOD":0.838143,"JPY":130.829938,"KES":127.602969,"KGS":100.225405,"KHR":4828.70738,"KMF":492.741079,"KPW":1063.852684,"KRW":1345.105273,"KWD":0.356032,"KYD":0.985044,"KZT":504.019189,"LAK":11227.187157,"LBP":1810.912689,"LKR":235.815617,"LRD":202.782408,"LSL":16.986265,"LTL":3.49031,"LVL":0.715015,"LYD":5.330971,"MAD":10.579128,"MDL":21.335608,"MGA":4556.833504,"MKD":61.566566,"MMK":1945.593749,"MNT":3364.135248,"MOP":9.455406,"MRO":421.99453,"MUR":50.597975,"MVR":18.200655,"MWK":945.64665,"MXN":23.647896,"MYR":4.912048,"MZN":75.09677,"NAD":16.986347,"NGN":486.419394,"NIO":41.578843,"NOK":10.281955,"NPR":140.678533,"NZD":1.686034,"OMR":0.455099,"PAB":1.182028,"PEN":4.613608,"PGK":4.143151,"PHP":58.847591,"PKR":187.179029,"PLN":4.511691,"PYG":8026.907563,"QAR":4.303918,"RON":4.927647,"RSD":117.38917,"RUB":87.864027,"RWF":1170.237497,"SAR":4.433619,"SBD":9.49454,"SCR":17.11642,"SDG":533.664832,"SEK":10.171125,"SGD":1.593295,"SHP":0.837894,"SLL":12149.192503,"SOS":691.503812,"SRD":24.918983,"STD":24124.027694,"SVC":10.342746,"SYP":1486.841937,"SZL":16.986436,"THB":38.157424,"TJS":13.481011,"TMT":4.137203,"TND":3.291439,"TOP":2.657207,"TRY":10.278705,"TTD":8.010435,"TWD":33.088998,"TZS":2741.192996,"UAH":32.237122,"UGX":4213.970207,"USD":1.182058,"UYU":51.636205,"UZS":12529.815471,"VEF":252759741497.0032,"VND":27198.565331,"VUV":128.183328,"WST":2.981119,"XAF":654.856251,"XAG":0.045298,"XAU":0.000659,"XCD":3.194571,"XDR":0.828707,"XOF":651.903598,"XPF":119.955315,"YER":295.810379,"ZAR":16.997052,"ZMK":10639.940699,"ZMW":26.781822,"ZWL":380.623092}}'

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s)).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    index  success   timestamp base        date         rates
0     AED     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.341698e+00
1     AFN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.397292e+01
2     ALL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.224688e+02
3     AMD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.858165e+02
4     ANG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.121734e+00
5     AOA     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.613033e+02
6     ARS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.133704e+02
7     AUD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.578498e+00
8     AWG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.127705e+00
9     AZN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.009632e+00
10    BAM     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.952573e+00
11    BBD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.386588e+00
12    BDT     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.002525e+02
13    BGN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.955599e+00
14    BHD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.451950e-01
15    BIF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.346976e+03
16    BMD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.182058e+00
17    BND     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.589828e+00
18    BOB     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.161781e+00
19    BRL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.127802e+00
20    BSD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.182028e+00
21    BTC     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.495064e-05
22    BTN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.792401e+01
23    BWP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.289702e+01
24    BYN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.002192e+00
25    BYR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.316834e+04
26    BZD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.382625e+00
27    CAD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.473897e+00
28    CDF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.367662e+03
29    CHF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.093020e+00
30    CLF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.197900e-02
31    CLP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.823943e+02
32    CNY     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.658792e+00
33    COP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.489989e+03
34    CRC     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.327576e+02
35    CUC     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.182058e+00
36    CUP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.132454e+01
37    CVE     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.106761e+02
38    CZK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.564912e+01
39    DJF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.100750e+02
40    DKK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.437261e+00
41    DOP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.751875e+01
42    DZD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.589937e+02
43    EGP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.854425e+01
44    ERN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.773323e+01
45    ETB     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.233564e+01
46    EUR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.000000e+00
47    FJD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.440927e+00
48    FKP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
49    GBP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.572230e-01
50    GEL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.729425e+00
51    GGP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
52    GHS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.009351e+00
53    GIP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
54    GMD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.042664e+01
55    GNF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.163736e+04
56    GTQ     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.160718e+00
57    GYD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.471046e+02
58    HKD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.180933e+00
59    HNL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.836895e+01
60    HRK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.486799e+00
61    HTG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.113758e+02
62    HUF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.536434e+02
63    IDR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.715468e+04
64    ILS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.871489e+00
65    IMP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
66    INR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.838301e+01
67    IQD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.726396e+03
68    IRR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.977056e+04
69    ISK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.467290e+02
70    JEP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
71    JMD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.767289e+02
72    JOD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.381430e-01
73    JPY     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.308299e+02
74    KES     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.276030e+02
75    KGS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.002254e+02
76    KHR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.828707e+03
77    KMF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.927411e+02
78    KPW     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.063853e+03
79    KRW     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.345105e+03
80    KWD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.560320e-01
81    KYD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.850440e-01
82    KZT     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.040192e+02
83    LAK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.122719e+04
84    LBP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.810913e+03
85    LKR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.358156e+02
86    LRD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.027824e+02
87    LSL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.698626e+01
88    LTL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.490310e+00
89    LVL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.150150e-01
90    LYD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.330971e+00
91    MAD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.057913e+01
92    MDL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.133561e+01
93    MGA     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.556834e+03
94    MKD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.156657e+01
95    MMK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.945594e+03
96    MNT     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.364135e+03
97    MOP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.455406e+00
98    MRO     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.219945e+02
99    MUR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.059797e+01
100   MVR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.820066e+01
101   MWK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.456467e+02
102   MXN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.364790e+01
103   MYR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.912048e+00
104   MZN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  7.509677e+01
105   NAD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.698635e+01
106   NGN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.864194e+02
107   NIO     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.157884e+01
108   NOK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.028195e+01
109   NPR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.406785e+02
110   NZD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.686034e+00
111   OMR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.550990e-01
112   PAB     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.182028e+00
113   PEN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.613608e+00
114   PGK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.143151e+00
115   PHP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.884759e+01
116   PKR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.871790e+02
117   PLN     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.511691e+00
118   PYG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.026908e+03
119   QAR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.303918e+00
120   RON     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.927647e+00
121   RSD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.173892e+02
122   RUB     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.786403e+01
123   RWF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.170237e+03
124   SAR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.433619e+00
125   SBD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  9.494540e+00
126   SCR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.711642e+01
127   SDG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.336648e+02
128   SEK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.017112e+01
129   SGD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.593295e+00
130   SHP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.378940e-01
131   SLL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.214919e+04
132   SOS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.915038e+02
133   SRD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.491898e+01
134   STD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.412403e+04
135   SVC     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.034275e+01
136   SYP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.486842e+03
137   SZL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.698644e+01
138   THB     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.815742e+01
139   TJS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.348101e+01
140   TMT     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.137203e+00
141   TND     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.291439e+00
142   TOP     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.657207e+00
143   TRY     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.027871e+01
144   TTD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.010435e+00
145   TWD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.308900e+01
146   TZS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.741193e+03
147   UAH     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.223712e+01
148   UGX     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.213970e+03
149   USD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.182058e+00
150   UYU     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  5.163620e+01
151   UZS     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.252982e+04
152   VEF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.527597e+11
153   VND     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.719857e+04
154   VUV     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.281833e+02
155   WST     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.981119e+00
156   XAF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.548563e+02
157   XAG     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  4.529800e-02
158   XAU     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.590000e-04
159   XCD     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.194571e+00
160   XDR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  8.287070e-01
161   XOF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  6.519036e+02
162   XPF     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.199553e+02
163   YER     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.958104e+02
164   ZAR     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.699705e+01
165   ZMK     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  1.063994e+04
166   ZMW     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  2.678182e+01
167   ZWL     True  1625593144  EUR  2021-07-06  3.806231e+02
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert the result into `json`-

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Now, filter the json object and convert it into a `dataframe`-

```
data = data['rates']
df = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
```

At last, set `currency` as index-

```
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)
```